# Legacy Constructor Violation: Swift constructors are preferred over legacy convenience functions. (legacy_constructor)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftlint

I'm getting a [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) warning on this line:

```
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, leftInset, bottomInset, rightInset)
```

This is the warning :

> Legacy Constructor Violation: Swift constructors are preferred over
>   legacy convenience functions. (legacy_constructor)

I'm getting a warning on this line as well:

```
return CGRectInset(bounds, insetX, insetY)
```

> Legacy CGGeometry Functions Violation: Struct extension properties and
>   methods are preferred over legacy functions
>   (legacy_cggeometry_functions)

What is the Swift version for `UIEdgeInsetsMake` and `CGRectInset` ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the reference https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiedgeinsets? Or try auto-completion: `return UIEdgeInsets(`

Comment: I did, but the Swift version bears the same name. So I don't know how to resolve this warning or if there is a different way of doing it.

Comment: The type is `UIEdgeInsets`, so start with `UIEdgeInsets(`, *not* `UIEdgeInsetsMake`...

Comment: Thank you! What about CGRectInset ?

Comment: Again, lookup up the CGRectInset documentation page, then switch to Swift, and you'll find https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1454218-insetby: `func insetBy(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat) -> CGRect`

Answer (score 17):

Swift wants you to update to the new struct initializers for those types, instead of the old C constructors. So your inset initializer would be changed to this:

```
return UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
```

The `CGRectInset` C method was changed to be a method on the `CGRect` struct.

```
return bounds.insetBy(dx: insetX, dy: insetY)
```

Comment: I ended up using UIEdgeInsets instead of UIEdgeInsetsMake as @Martin R suggested.

Comment: Thats what I meant to write. `UIEdgeInsetsMake` was a type on my part.